# swap "disable in viewports" and "disable in renders"

Tags: 3d-view, performance

I'm working on a big project and to improve performance I have hidden a lot of modifiers and objects in viewports. But now I want to see how the current full version of the project looks like in object mode and with the ability to look around.

is there a way to swap "disable in viewports" and "disable in renders"? 
or is there another way to get the same effect?